# Adding html class in react dynamically using function?

Tags: reactjs, class

I am making a pen where when user clicks on hamburger icon (top left), I want it to open the sidebar. I saw a thread on SO explaining how to do it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33262493/how-to-add-a-class-with-react-js).

In short, the solution is to do something like this:

```
isActive:function(value){
    return 'btn '+((value===this.state.selected) ?'active':'default');
  },
```

I am trying to do something similar (a little different); here is what I did:

```
expandSidebar(){
    this.setState({active: !this.state.active});
    console.log(this.state.active ? "square-left active" : "square-left");
    return this.state.active ? "square-left active" : "square-left"
  }
...

//different React component
<div className={this.props.expandSidebar}>
...
```

But it does not work. My goal is to display the sidebar when it is clicked, by adding `active` class. When I console log it, it returns the right string, `"square-left active"`.

This is the codepen: https://codepen.io/iggPen/pen/BdEJmw

What did I do wrong? I am pretty sure it is returning `square-left active`, but it is not displaying sidebar.

Comment: In your pen change `<SidebarRectangle expandSidebar={this.expandSidebar} />` to `<SidebarRectangle expandSidebar={this.expandSidebar()} />`

Comment: Hi Prakash, it didn't work. When I do `<SidebarRectangle expandSidebar={this.expandSidebar()} />`, everything disappeared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't pass a function as `className`.
You should pass a prop of active and do the `className` logic inside the `SidebarRectangle` component.
For example (i've added an `active` prop to this component):
`this.props.active ? "square-left active" : "square-left"`

Modified version of your code:

```js
const sidebarOptions = ["Sidebars", "Are", "Super", "Cool"]

class SidebarRectangle extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <div className={this.props.active ? "square-left active" : "square-left"}>
        {sidebarOptions.map((option, index) => {
          return (
            <div onClick={this.props.expandSidebar} key={index} className="sidebar-element">{option}</div>
            )
        })}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
class MainRectangle extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      active: false
    };
    this.expandSidebar = this.expandSidebar.bind(this);
  }
  expandSidebar(){
    this.setState({active: !this.state.active});
    console.log(this.state.active ? "square-left active" : "square-left");
    return this.state.active ? "square-left active" : "square-left"
  }
  render(){
    return (
    <div className="center">
      <SidebarRectangle expandSidebar={this.expandSidebar} active={this.state.active} />
      <div className="square-main">
        <div className="square-header">
          <span onClick={this.expandSidebar} className="header-notification clickable"><i className="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
          <span className="header-notification">Notifications</span>
          <span></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    )
  }
}
class Application extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <MainRectangle />
      </div>
      )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```css
body {
  background: #4FB5FB;
  font-family: "Arial";
}

.center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}

.square-main {
  position: absolute;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: flex;
}

.square-header {
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  background: #DD0031;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.header-notification {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.clickable {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.square-left {
  width: 130px;
  height: 225px;
  background: #199FFA;
  position: absolute;
  left: -150px;
  top: -110px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
}

.active {
  transform: translate3d(-150px, 0, 0);
}

.sidebar-element {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've cleaned up your code a bit, and attached is a working example:

- Application can be pure functional component, as it only renders
- SidebarRectangle could be aswell, as it doesn't have any state
- Classnames for sidebar should be defined in that component
- Your constructor for MainRectangle can be simplified
- You don't need to pass a callback function as rendered sidebar items aren't clickable in your example
- onClick inside SidebarRectangle is not required, as these aren't buttons in your example that can be clicked.

```js
const sidebarOptions = ["Sidebars", "Are", "Super", "Cool"];

class SidebarRectangle extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { isActive } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className={`${isActive ? "square-left active" : "square-left"}`}>
        { sidebarOptions.map((option, index) => {
          return (
            <div key={index} className="sidebar-element">{option}</div>
            )
        }) }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class MainRectangle extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isActive: false
  }

  handleExpandSidebar = () => {
    this.setState({ isActive: !this.state.isActive });
  }

  render(){
    const { isActive } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="center">
        <SidebarRectangle isActive={isActive} />
        <div className="square-main">
          <div className="square-header">
            <span onClick={this.handleExpandSidebar} className="header-notification clickable"><i className="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true" /></span>
            <span className="header-notification">Notifications</span>
            <span></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const Application = () => {
  return(
    <div>
      <MainRectangle />
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```css
body {
  background: #4FB5FB;
  font-family: "Arial";
}

.center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}

.square-main {
  position: absolute;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: flex;
}

.square-header {
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  background: #DD0031;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.header-notification {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.clickable {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.square-left {
  width: 130px;
  height: 225px;
  background: #199FFA;
  position: absolute;
  left: -150px;
  top: -110px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
}

.active {
  transform: translate3d(-150px, 0, 0);
}

.sidebar-element {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```